# Can I delete files from my dyld folder?

Tags: storage, macos, space

I have a 13-inch Early 2015 MacBook Air (OS 11.2.5) with 128 GB, and I'm trying to clear some space for a game I want to install. So far, I've transferred my school assignment files into my external hard drive, and I've safely cleared my Music cache, which took over about 40% of my storage before. I currently have 51.36 GB available but I still want to clear more space. I saw this dyld folder and it had the largest amount of gigabytes I've seen ever since I cleared the Music cache folder; 9.78 GB!

Location:
~/System/Library/dyld

Can I delete my dyld folder, or at least several items of it only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of macOS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Is it `~/System/Library/dyld` or rather `/System/Library/dyld`? I can't find the former, but the latter exists on my Mac running Big Sur. As a general rule, **don't delete anything** under `/System`.